# I created collapse in React, I used different useState for each click, but I want to use only one useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
    function Solution() {
    const [firstClick,setFirstClick] = useState(true);
    const [secondClick,setSecondClick] = useState(true);
    const [thirdClick,setThirdClick] = useState(true);
    const [fourthClick,setFourthClick] = useState(true);
    const [fivethClick,setFivethClick] = useState(true);
    const [sixthClick,setSixthClick] = useState(true);
    const [seventhClick,setSeventhClick] = useState(true);

    const changeIconFirst = () => {
    firstClick ? setFirstClick(false) : setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)

    }
    const changeIconSecond = () => {
    secondClick ? setSecondClick(false) : setSecondClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)
    }
    const changeIconThird = () => {
    thirdClick ? setThirdClick(false) : setThirdClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)
    }
    const changeIconFourth = () => {
    fourthClick ? setFourthClick(false) : setFourthClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)
    }
    const changeIconFiveth = () => {
    fivethClick ? setFivethClick(false) : setFivethClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)
    }
    const changeIconSixth = () => {
    sixthClick ? setSixthClick(false) : setSixthClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSeventhClick(true)
    }
    const changeIconSeventh = () => {
    seventhClick ? setSeventhClick(false) : setSeventhClick(true);
    setFirstClick(true);
    setSecondClick(true);
    setThirdClick(true);
    setFourthClick(true);
    setFivethClick(true);
    setSixthClick(true);
    }
```

I used more than one useState to open collapse when I clicked it, but I want to set up a simpler and more dynamic structure by using one useState instead of more than one. By doing if else with the true false method, I changed the className to enable collapse to open and close. I did not think of it in the method. I am waiting for your suggestions to create a more dynamic and simpler structure.

Comment: Instead of `boolean`, store the index of the expanded one in the state, then collapse/expand based on that, e.g: `<div className={item.index === expandedIndex ? 'open': 'close'}>`

Comment: It's a very good idea, I got it, just where to define expandedIndex and what to define its value as

Comment: If you use a loop to create your expandable elements, just use the loop's index, e.g `i`, as each item's index, then update `expandedIndex`  using that, e.g: `onClick={e=> setExpandedIndex(i)}`. and of course, you should define the state first, like so: `const [expandedIndex, setExpandedIndex] = userState(0)`, otherwise just hard code the value, e.g: 1,2, 3, ...

Answer (score 0):

This code should work just fine if you have any questions go ahead and ask

```js
function Solution() {
  //this is your main useState that will take control of your collapse
  const [collapse , setCollapse] = useState(true);

  // this is your collapse button you should give it an on click event
  <button onClick={() =>setCollapse(!collapse)}>collapse </button>;
}
```

Edited :

```js
function Solution() {
  const [clicks, setClicks] = useState({
    firstClick: true,
    secondClick: true,
    thirdClick: true,
    fourthClick: true,
    fivethClick: true,
    sixthClick: true,
    seventhClick: true,
  });

  const changeIconFirst = () => {
    setClicks({
      firstClick: clicks.firstClick ? true : false,
      secondClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconSecond = () => {
    setClicks({
      secondClick: clicks.secondClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconThird = () => {
    setClicks({
      thirdClick: clicks.thirdClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      secondClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconFourth = () => {
    setClicks({
      fourthClick: clicks.fourthClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      secondClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconFiveth = () => {
    setClicks({
      fivethClick: clicks.fivethClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      secondClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconSixth = () => {
    setClicks({
      sixthClick: clicks.sixthClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      secondClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      seventhClick: true,
    });
  };
  const changeIconSeventh = () => {
    setClicks({
      seventhClick: clicks.seventhClick ? true : false,
      firstClick: true,
      secondClick: true,
      thirdClick: true,
      fourthClick: true,
      fivethClick: true,
      sixthClick: true,
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: In such a case, they all open at once, they all close at once I want the thing I press to open, then if I press it again, I want it to close, or if I press another collapse, I want the open collapse to close and the collapse I pressed will open

Comment: I got u 
Check my answer I did update it

Comment: Come on man this is exactly what i did, read well what i want

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use one single component then u can accomplish by giving each collapse a index.

in the render

```
<button onClick={()=> setId(1)}>Click</button> // can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

in your collapse it can be something like

```
<CollapseComponent show={id === 1} />
<CollapseComponent show={id === 2} />
<CollapseComponent show={id === 3} />
```

I notice the question speaks about clicking multiple times. so onClick can be changed to as follows

```
const onClick = () => {
     if (id === 7) { //assuming there's 8 pics
        setId(0)
     } else {
        setId(prev => prev+1)
     }
}

<button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
```

Comment: I don't like this path including a dynamic path

Comment: u will notice u will eventually go this path if you want to open only 1 collapse at one time. I've updated answer to record number of clicks.